# jQuery - animate() properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, variables

I'm using jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function like this:

```
var css1 = {
      display: "block",
      marginTop: 20
    };

var direction = "marginTop";

$(element).animate(css1, 150, 'swing');
```

Notice the `marginTop` property above. Well I want to replace that with the **direction** variable, but it doesn't work for some reason. Does anyone know why?

Later edit:
Basically I want to replace:

```
var css1 = {
      display: "block",
      marginTop: 20
    };
```

with

```
var css1 = {
      display: "block",
      direction: 20
    };
```

The problem is that jQuery doesn't seem to recognize "direction" as the "marginTop" property

Comment: what code exactly doesn't work? There is no code here that attempts what you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a dynamic property like you want using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation), like this:

```
var direction = "marginTop";
var css1 = { display: "block" };
css1[direction] = 20;

$(element).animate(css1, 150, 'swing');
```

Doing `css1.marginTop` can also be accessed via  `css1["marginTop"]`, and you can use a variable for the second (bracket notation) version.